# How to access data in nested Std Object array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to access the data: 'hotelID', 'name', 'address1','city' etc. I have the following Std Object array ($the_obj) in PHP that contains the following data:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'HotelListResponse' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'customerSessionId' => string '0ABAAA87-6BDD-6F91-4292-7F90AF49146E' (length=36)
      public 'numberOfRoomsRequested' => int 0
      public 'moreResultsAvailable' => boolean false
      public 'HotelList' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public '@size' => string '227' (length=3)
          public '@activePropertyCount' => string '227' (length=3)
          public 'HotelSummary' => 
            array (size=227)
             0 =>
              object(stdClass)[4]
              public 'hotelId' => 112304 
              public 'name' => La Quinta Inn and Suites Seattle Downtown 
              public 'address1' => 2224 8th Ave 
              public 'city' => Seattle 
              public 'stateProvinceCode' => WA 
              public 'postalCode' => 98121 
              public 'countryCode' => US 
              public 'airportCode' => SEA 
              public 'propertyCategory' => 1 
              public 'hotelRating' => 2.5
```

**I have tried the following for lets say to access the 'name':**

```
echo $the_obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary[0]->name;
```

**Also I have tried to print each key and value pairs by using foreach loop but I keep on getting errors. Here is what I tried:**

```
foreach ($the_obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary[0] as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

**Here are the errors that I get:**

- Trying to get property of non-object
- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Did you test step by step? For example: `$the_obj->HotelListResponse;` Next `$the_obj->HotelListResponse->HotelList;` etc.. and find out where the problem is...

Comment: It seems like it's actual data structure & structure on screen mismatch. Most common reason - you've dumped another data, while accessed something else. Are you sure that's `var_dump($the_obj)`? (output is different from it. try to do this `var_dump`)

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili yes I did test it out step by step, the only deep I can access is:  `$the_obj->HotelListResponse->customerSessionId` (in fact the public members of the HotelListResponse are all accessible ). If I go further more deeper, then I get an error

Comment: I have also dumped the variables to see the stored data, but the `var_dump` only displays the data up to 3 nested object arrays and further it shows it by '...' (that the data is continued)

Comment: One way to look deeper in this problem would be to serialize that object save to file and post link here, so we could examine object itself. If you can

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Actually I am getting this data from an API, therefore the data I mentioned above is a small bit of large data, therefore it is not possible to serialize that.

Comment: OK understand but to be able solve the problem we should see what's actually going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone for answering, I have figured out the way to access the 'hotelID', 'name' and all other keys and value pairs in the deepest nest of the array.

**I converted the Std Object array to an associative array, then I accessed each of the value by using the foreach loop:**

```
foreach ($the_obj["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"]["HotelSummary"] as $value){
echo $value["hotelId"];
echo $value["name"];

//and all other values can be accessed
}
```

**To access both (Keys as well as values):**

```
foreach ($the_obj["HotelListResponse"]["HotelList"]["HotelSummary"] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.'=>'.$value["hotelId"];
    echo $key.'=>'.$value["name"];

    //and all other keys as well as values can be accessed
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to @Satya's answer I'd like to show simpler way for Object to array conversion, by using `json` functions:

```
$obj = ...
$tmp = json_encode($obj);
$objToArray = json_decode($tmp,true);
```

This way you can easily access array items. First you can dump structure...

Answer (score -1):

try something like this :

```
 $p=objectToArray($result);
recurse($p);
}

function objectToArray( $object )
    {
        if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
        {
            return $object;
        }
        if( is_object( $object ) )
        {
            $object = get_object_vars( $object );
        }
        return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
    }
function recurse ($array)
{
    //statements
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        # code...
        if( is_array( $value ) )
        {   
          recurse( $value );
        }
        else
        {   $v=$value;
            $v=str_replace("&rsquo;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&ndash;",'-',$v);
            $v=str_replace("&lsquo;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&ldquo;",'"',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&rdquo;",'"',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&#8211;",'-',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&#8217;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&#39;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&nbsp;",'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=html_entity_decode($v);
            $v=str_replace("&",' and ',$v);

        $v =  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $v);
            if($key=="image")
            {
                if(strlen($v)==0)
                {
                    echo '<'.$key .'>NA</'.$key.'>';
                }
                else 
                {
                echo '<'.$key .'>'. trim($v)  .'</'.$key.'>';
                }
            }
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: removed ereg_Replace , try and let me know please